# Dart Flutter What is the Difference Between Import and Extends?

Tags: flutter, inheritance, dart, import, extends

I still do not understand the difference between importing a class and extending a class. I mean if I just import the class I can still use its constructor and methods, so what is the advantage of using `extends`?

Feel free to use the two classes I provided or change them to your convenience.

```
Class A {
  final String a;
  A({this.a});
  void printA(){
    print(this.a);
  }
}

Class B {
  final String b;
  B({this.b});
  void printB(){
    print(this.b);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `import` statement makes another class visible in that file.

The `extends` keyword makes a class inherit from another class.

When you say `class B extends A`, B has inherited all the properties and methods of A.

As a reference: https://medium.com/run-dart/dart-dartlang-introduction-object-oriented-programming-c3d79d94d303

Comment: thank you for your answer, still when I import I can access the imported class's properties and methods.

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of importing. You can access them by creating an instance of the class (or accessing their static members directly). Where's the confusion?

Comment: It is that I don't see the use of extending a class I can access all of its properties and methods just by importing it.

Comment: Extending a class is used if you want OOP (like Circle or Rectangle are different both different classes but both can be classified as type Shape - which is their superclass).